# How to use ActionListener on a ComboBox to give a variable a value

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

Im using BlueJ and I have run into problem. I have a combo box with 3 options. Each option is a string. The three options are Day, Week, and Month. What I want to do is if Day is picked than a variable equals 30 (a double) and so on. Can someone help me buy telling me how to give "emailvalue" a value based on the selected option in the combobox?

EDIT: Im going to add my actual program code which is a monthly data calculater. It does compile.

Here is the code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    /** 
    * @author (Andrew Napier, Sikander Singh) 
    * @version (December 18th, 2012)
    */
    public class MonthlyData extends JFrame
    {
    private JLabel title, stitle, l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12,l13,l14;
    private JLabel l15,l16,l17,l18,l19,l20,l21,l22,l23,l24,l25,l26,l27,l28,l29;
    private JLabel Usage,Estimated,solu1,solu2,total2;
    private JPanel  panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5, panel6, panel7;
    String[] deviceStrings = { "Blackberry", "Other", "Internetstick"};
    String[] date = { "Day", "Week", "Month"};
    public double email2 = 0;
    public double email1;
    static final int email50 = 50;
    static final int email100 = 100;
    static final int email150 = 150;
    static final int email200 = 200;
    static final int email250 = 250;
    static final int email300 = 300;
    public JSlider Email = new JSlider(0,300,0);
    public JSlider Web = new JSlider(0,500,0);
    public JSlider IM = new JSlider(0,500,0);
    public JSlider Video = new JSlider(0,300,0);
    public JSlider Song = new JSlider(0,200,0);
    public  JSlider App_G = new JSlider(0,100,0);
    public String currentdate;        
    public double emailvalue;
    public MonthlyData ()
    {
        super ("MonthlyData");
        setSize (1000,1100);    
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// panel1
        panel1 = new JPanel ();                                              
        panel1.setLayout (new GridLayout(1,1));
        panel1.setVisible(true);
        panel1.setBackground (Color.black);
        title = new JLabel ("                                     WANNA KNOW HOW MUCH DATA",JLabel.LEFT);
        title.setForeground(Color.white);
        title.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,25));
        l1 = new JLabel ("");
        l2 = new JLabel ("");
        /////////////////////////////////////////////// panel2   
        panel2 = new JPanel ();                                             
        panel2.setLayout (new GridLayout(1,1));
        panel2.setVisible(true);
        panel2.setBackground (Color.gray);
        stitle = new JLabel ("           PICK A PHONE OR INTERNET STICK AND THEN DRAG THE .",JLabel.LEFT);
        stitle.setForeground(Color.black);
        stitle.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,14));
        //////////////////////////////////////////////// panel3
        panel3 = new JPanel ();                                              
        panel3.setLayout (new FlowLayout());
        panel3.setVisible(true);
        panel3.setBackground (Color.white);
        l3 = new JLabel ("Select Your Device:",JLabel.RIGHT);
        l3.setForeground(Color.red);
        JComboBox devicelist = new JComboBox (deviceStrings);
        l4 = new JLabel ("Tell us how much of what's listed here you think you'll use:");
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////// panel4    
        panel4 = new JPanel ();                                               
        panel4.setLayout (new GridLayout(6,7));
        panel4.setVisible(true);
        panel4.setBackground (Color.white);
        l5 = new JLabel ("Email");
        l6 = new JLabel ("WebPage");
        l7 = new JLabel ("Instant Message");
        l8 = new JLabel ("Streaming Video");
        l9 = new JLabel ("Song");
        l10 = new JLabel ("Application or Game");    
        l11 = new JLabel (""+" Emails");
        final JComboBox date1 = new JComboBox (date);
           date1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//add actionlistner to listen for change
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
                String s = (String) date1.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item    
                switch (s) {//check for a match
                    case "Day":
                        emailvalue = 30;                            
                        break;
                    case "Week":
                        emailvalue = 4;                            
                        break;
                    case "Month":
                        emailvalue = 1;
                        System.out.println("Month selected, emailvalue:" + emailvalue);
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        });

        l12 = new JLabel ("   0.002 MB");    
        l13 = new JLabel (""+email2+" MB");
        double web1 = 0;
        l14 = new JLabel (""+web1+" WebPages");
        JComboBox date2 = new JComboBox (date);
        l15 = new JLabel ("  0.07 MB");
        double web2 = 0;
        l16 = new JLabel (""+web2+" MB");
        double IM1 = 0;
        l17 = new JLabel (""+IM1+" IMs");
        JComboBox date3 = new JComboBox (date);
        l18 = new JLabel ("  0.005 MB");
        double IM2 = 0;
        l19 = new JLabel (""+IM2+" MB");
        double video1 = 0;
        l20 = new JLabel (""+video1+" Minutes");
        JComboBox date4 = new JComboBox (date);
        l21 = new JLabel ("   1 MB");
        double video2 = 0;
        l22 = new JLabel (""+video2+" MB");
        double song1 = 0;
        l23 = new JLabel (""+song1+" MP3's");
        JComboBox date5 = new JComboBox (date);
        l24 = new JLabel ("    4 MB");
        double song2 = 0;
        l25 = new JLabel (""+song2+" MB");
        double app1 = 0;
        l26 = new JLabel (""+app1+" App/Games");
        JComboBox date6 = new JComboBox (date);
        l27 = new JLabel ("   0.44 MB");
        double app2 = 0;
        l28 = new JLabel (""+app2+" MB");
        //////////////////////////////////////////////// panel5
        panel5 = new JPanel ();                                            
        panel5.setLayout (new GridLayout(1,1));
        panel5.setVisible(true);
        panel5.setBackground (Color.white);
        solu1 = new JLabel ("WE THINK YOUR MONTHLY DATA USAGE WILL BE:");
        solu1.setForeground (Color.red);
        solu1.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20));
        double total = 0;
        total2 = new JLabel (""+total+" MB");
        total2.setForeground (Color.red);
        total2.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20));
        /////////////////////////////////////////// panel6
        panel6 = new JPanel ();
        panel6.setLayout (new GridLayout (1,1));
        panel6.setVisible (true);
        panel6.setBackground (Color.white);
        Usage = new JLabel ("Usage per unit");
        Usage.setForeground (Color.red);
        Estimated = new JLabel ("     Estimated total");
        Estimated.setForeground (Color.red);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////// panel7
        panel7 = new JPanel ();
        panel7.setLayout (new GridLayout (1,1));
        panel7.setVisible (true);
        panel7.setBackground (Color.white);
        solu2 = new JLabel ("Data usage varies by device and other factors and the .");
        solu2.setForeground (Color.black);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////// Implements
        Container container = getContentPane ();
        container.setLayout (null);      //changed
        container.setBackground (Color.white);

        container.add (panel1).setBounds (0,0,1000,120);        //panel1
        panel1.add (title).setSize(500,500);

        container.add (panel2).setBounds (0,100,1000,120);      //panel2
        panel2.add (stitle);

        container.add (panel3).setBounds (0,220,1000,100);      //panel3
        panel3.add (l3);
        panel3.add (devicelist);
        panel3.add (l4);

        container.add (panel4).setBounds (0,340,1000,150);      //panel4
        Email.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
        Web.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
        IM.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
        Video.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
        Song.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
        App_G.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());

        panel4.add (l5);
        panel4.add (Email);
        panel4.add (l11);
        panel4.add (date1);
        panel4.add (l12);
        panel4.add (l13);
        panel4.add (l6);
        panel4.add (Web);
        panel4.add (l14);
        panel4.add (date2);
        panel4.add (l15);
        panel4.add (l16);
        panel4.add (l7);
        panel4.add (IM);
        panel4.add (l17);
        panel4.add (date3);
        panel4.add (l18);
        panel4.add (l19);
        panel4.add (l8);
        panel4.add (Video);
        panel4.add (l20);
        panel4.add (date4);
        panel4.add (l21);
        panel4.add (l22);
        panel4.add (l9);
        panel4.add (Song);
        panel4.add (l23);
        panel4.add (date5);
        panel4.add (l24);
        panel4.add (l25);
        panel4.add (l10);
        panel4.add (App_G);
        panel4.add (l26);
        panel4.add (date6);
        panel4.add (l27);
        panel4.add (l28);
        container.add (panel5).setBounds (210,540,1000,50);    // panel5
        panel5.add (solu1);
        panel5.add (total2);
        container.add (panel6).setBounds (670,220,200,220);      // panel6
        panel6.add (Usage);
        panel6.add (Estimated);

        container.add (panel7).setBounds (210,580,530,50);    // panel7
        panel7.add (solu2);

        Email.setOpaque(false);
        Web.setOpaque(false);
        IM.setOpaque(false); 
        Video.setOpaque(false); 
        Song.setOpaque(false);
        App_G.setOpaque(false); 
        setVisible (true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        MonthlyData application = new MonthlyData ();
    }        

    public class SliderHandler implements ChangeListener
    {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource().equals(Email))
            {
                l11.setText(""+Email.getValue());    
                email2= (Email.getValue() * 0.002);
                l13.setText(email2 + "MB");
            }
            if (e.getSource().equals(Web))
            {
                l14.setText(""+Web.getValue());
            }    
            if (e.getSource().equals(IM))
            {
                l17.setText(""+IM.getValue());
            }    
            if (e.getSource().equals(Video))
            {
                l20.setText(""+Video.getValue());
            }    
            if (e.getSource().equals(Song))
            {
                l23.setText(""+Song.getValue());
            }    
            if (e.getSource().equals(App_G))
            {
                l26.setText(""+App_G.getValue());
            }    
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Well firstly you'd need an `ActionListener` added to the `JComboBox` to listen for selected item changes.

2) Within `actionPerformed(...)` of `ActionListener` get the selected item via `getSelectedItem()` and cast to a `String` as the method returns an `Object`.

3) Use a `switch` statement to check which one the selected item matches i.e day, month,week and than assign a value accordingly.

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MonthlyData {

    public double emailvalue;
    private String[] date = {"Day", "Week", "Month"};
    private JFrame frame;

    public MonthlyData() {
        frame = new JFrame();//use an instance rather than extending the class
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final JComboBox date1 = new JComboBox(date);

        ActionListener cbActionListener = new ActionListener() {//add actionlistner to listen for change
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String s = (String) date1.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item

                switch (s) {//check for a match
                    case "Day":
                        emailvalue = 1.1;
                        System.out.println("Day selected, emailvalue:" + emailvalue);
                        break;
                    case "Week":
                        emailvalue = 2.2;
                        System.out.println("Week selected, emailvalue:" + emailvalue);
                        break;
                    case "Month":
                        emailvalue = 3.3;
                        System.out.println("Month selected, emailvalue:" + emailvalue);
                        break;
                    default:
                        emailvalue = 4.4;
                        System.out.println("No match selected, emailvalue:" + emailvalue);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        date1.addActionListener(cbActionListener);

        frame.add(date1);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MonthlyData();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After you added an SSCCE and commented:

> If you go down to the SliderHandler class, type in
>   email2=(Email.getValue() * 0.002)*emailvalue; if you do the label wont
>   update in real time. but if you replace emailvalue with lets say 5, it
>   will update

The problem is

On start up the `emailvalue` is not yet set. It will only be set on the first time the selected item/index is changed.

To solve this we must simply give it a default selected value by calling `setSelectedItem(..)` before its visible:

```
final JComboBox date1 = new JComboBox(date);
date1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//add actionlistner to listen for change
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String s = (String) date1.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item

        switch (s) {//check for a match
            case "Day":
                emailvalue = 30;
                break;
            case "Week":
                emailvalue = 4;
                break;
            case "Month":
                emailvalue = 1;
                System.out.println("Month selected, emailvalue:" + emailvalue);
                break;
        }
    }
});
date1.setSelectedItem(date[0]);//set Day as default selected item/emailvalue
```

**Suggestions on your code:**

- Swing components should be created and manipulated on [`EDT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)` block.
- Dont override `paint(..)` of `JFrame` rather add `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`
- Dont call `setBounds` or `setSize` rather use an appropriate `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` and return `Dimension`s which fit its contents than call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible.
- Dont extend `JFrame` unnecessarily
- Dont implement `ActionListener` on the class unless the class will be used as one and or its methods must be exposed to other classes

Comment: I didnt post all the code, I only posted the combobox bits. Im making a program in which I have to add Jpanels etc, so I thought itd be easier to extend Jframe

Comment: @Sunny No this is bad practice we should only extend a class if we want to add functionality that doesnt already exist/is beyond the capabilities through simple method calls. Also seen as you are new please have a read on: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as this will apply once you have found a suitable solution.

Comment: It makes sure the compiler knows we are overriding a specific method from another class. Thus if we dont override the method correctly i.e we put the wrong name or something, a compiler error would be given as we added the `@Override` annotation. If we didnt it would have compiled and assumed we aded a new method. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) for more

Comment: Again if I use (new ActionListener) I get a error that says its abstract and cannot be instantiated

Comment: @Sunny I have tested my code it compiles fine, please copy and paste my snippet and test it rather than copying pieces. Also Id need to see code to give you a reason for the error. Tough its sounds like you are trying to do `ActionListener al=new ActionListener();` which cannot be done as this class is abstract and thus must override `actionPerformed`

Comment: @Sunny edit your question to reflect an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Than I can see what up with your code.

Comment: Basically what Im doing is getting a value from a Jslider and multiplying it by the emailvalue to update a label in real time. But If I multiply it by emailvalue, it doesnt update in real time, but if I replace email value with a number, it updates

Comment: If you go down to the SliderHandler class, type in email2=(Email.getValue() * 0.002)*emailvalue; if you do the label wont update in real time. but if you replace emailvalue with lets say 5, it will update

Answer (score 1):

Add a `actionListener` to the `JComboBox`:

```
JComboBox date1 = new JComboBox (date);
date1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String selectedItem = (String) date1.getSelectedItem();
        if(selectedItem.equals("date")
        {
            emailValue = 30;
        }
    }
});
```

Since your class already implements `ActionListener`, you can do this as well (as an alternative to the above):

Add a `actionCommand` to your `JComboBox`:

```
JComboBox date1 = new JComboBox (date);
date1.setActionCommand("date1");
date1.addActionListener(this)
```

Note: `date1` should be a class level variable (field) so that it is accessible to the `actionPerformed` method.

Add an `actionPerformed` method to the class (you most likely already have this).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("date1")
    {
        String selectedItem = date1.getSelectedItem();
        if(selectedItem.equals("date")
        {
           emailValue = 30;
        }
        …
        //Note: From Java 7, you can use Strings with switch
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code Nivas but when I run it I get a error saying java.awt.event.ActionListener is abstract; cannot be instantiated. If I try date1.addActionListener(this) I get a error that says cannot find variable data 1 and it highlights data1.getselectedItem()

Comment: @Sunny: You need to have `date1.addActionListener(this)` (added to answer). For this date1 should be a class level variable.

Comment: I tried your second answer and I get an error which says incompatible types and it highlights String selectedItem = date1.getselectedItem();

Comment: -1 for uncompilable code after OP has said its not working giving the line and all. @Sunny Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14306189/1133011) you should cast the returned value to a `String` as said in my answer (the method returns an `Object`) like so: `String selectedItem = (String)date1.getselectedItem();`

Comment: @Sunny You need to cast to String as getSelectedItem returns a Object. I have updated the code.
@ DavidKroukamp The answer is just a pointer to the right approach. Basic compiler errors should be easy to resolve. My intention is not to provide working code. My intention is to provide the right approach.

Comment: @Nivas lifted my downvote accordingly though I disagree with *My intention is not to provide working code* than you are in fact not helping at all if the code does not work, rather just complicating the matter.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp My point was that it wouldn't be that difficult to identify and resolve the error. Still, I agree it is not fair to give an snippet that would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a map and use it in selection listener.

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap();
map.put("Day",1);
map.put("Week",7);
map.put("Month",30);
```

Answer (score -2):

this is just an example

```
implements ItemListener //on your class addItemListener to your combo


public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

     String i = "" + cboMonth.getSelectedItem();
     String b = "" + cboMonth1.getSelectedItem();
     System.out.println("The number  Start:" + i);
     System.out.println("The number End:" + b);
     if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
          int mSatrt = Integer.parseInt(i);
          int mEnd = Integer.parseInt(b);
          // System.out.println("The number m FROM ITEMSTATE is:" + mSatrt +"   == " + "M1 is :  "+ mEnd);

          if(mSatrt >= mEnd){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, " Next Date Payment est moin que la date de paiement" + mSatrt + ">=" + "" + mEnd);}
              //else if (mSatrt> mEnd) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "la date Erroné" + mSatrt + ">" + "" + mEnd);}
              //else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "la date Erroné" + mSatrt + "=" + "" + mEnd);}
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your answer to describe a little more.